# Blackberry Bold browser - h3 (clickable element) - browser inserts blue background

Tags: css, blackberry, mobile

There is another posting on stackoverflow titled "Blackberry browser automatically inserts blue background". This is very similar to what I am seeing, but not exactly the same. I've tried to apply the fix "outline:none" to my element, but I am still seeing the blue background.

It appears that the blue background is being applied by default in the Blackberry Bold 9650 browser. Is there a way to override this using CSS?

thanks

Comment: is the h3 a clickable link, like `<a href="#"><h3>link</h3></a>`, or is it being made clicklable through another means?

Comment: It is being made clickable through javascript.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was adding **outline: 0 none;** to my css. It seemed to be the combination of both "0" and "none". Since I don't have an actual device to test on, I was using Device Anywhere to recreate the issue. So, I wasn't able to spend a bunch of time figuring out exactly overrode the default. I wanted to let you all know it is resolved, though.